Why is SpeedTest and gaming are fine, but trouble loading websites on one particular PC?

PC: Aurora Alienware R8
OS: Windows 10
Internet: Cabled

Issue that started last Friday evening: Can't load websites properly, or at all, especially images and videos. Online gaming works fine, speedtests say everything is good. It's only the case for this particular PC - loading youtube for example on a different PC or a mobile phone works just fine.
What I've tried so far without any results:

Tried changing DNS in my ConnectBox (modem supplied by ISP), but it does not have that functionality. Restarted that device as well.
Changed IPv4 and IPv6 DNS settings to Google as well as Cloudflare during separate tests on my PC itself by going into the Ethernet Adapter settings in Windows. I did use /flushdns in case you're wondering.
Turning off IPv6 completely in my ethernet adapter settings.
Tried a different browser without any add-ons or adblockers or anything. It can barely load any advertisements let alone the video.
Tried the Windows internet troubleshooter.
Checked whether DHCP is enabled - it is.
Checked the lights on the back of my PC where the ethernet cable plugs in. There's a solid orange/amber light and a blinking yellow one. I don't know how else to see if my ethernet card is fried.
I checked whether there have been any driver updates recently, and according to some menu in Windows itself there haven't been any in a while
I checked the "reliability checker" in Windows, it doesn't say anything about internet issues
Running tracert in a command prompt to for example youtube.com sometimes has requests time out while most of the traces/pings do just fine.
My Steam library games update at good speeds and the Steam Store images and videos load normally.
I swapped out the ethernet cable for a known working one without any change.
I checked my MTU size and it appears to be at it's workable maximum.

EDIT: If anyone finds this later because they have similar issues - the culprit turned out to be AVG Antivirus.

Please clarify what exactly doesn't load fine. Does it eventually load, but its slow? Or at the place of images, you get [x] icons? Also, what happens if you use another browser? To rule out a corrupt browser profile or corrupt cache.

I have tried Edge and Firefox with the same results.
As for what doesn't load - Youtube videos don't load, or load at the lowest possible resolution. Putting it back on my usual resolution makes them not load at all. Sometimes a little bit loads before it stops buffering.
Images on image boards don't load at all, or half-load and stop (top half loaded, bottom half not, for example). Sometimes they eventually load in full after an extremely long time. Sometimes they only load after refreshing a few times.
Video thumbnails and smaller image previews tend to load normal-ish.

Can you say more about how you checked your MTU size and determined that it's okay?

Did you check both upload and download speed with speedtest? an upload speed that is really bad will stall the download speed because it can't send confirmation packages quickly.

Does your Ethernet cord from your PC go directly to a LAN port of your main router, or is there something else in the path? Wi-Fi, MoCA, and powerline are not Ethernet and have a bunch of problems Ethernet doesn't have,  but sometimes people leave out that they're not using actual Ethernet the whole way. So I have to ask.

Yeah I did test both speeds. My download speed is 660 Mbps and my upload speed is 48 Mbps.

I was linked a video about MTU size. I checked my modem and it has MTU settings. Those were already at the max (1500) by default. I used the ping method outlined in the video and confirmed that my max MTU is 1472 + 28 = 1500. So my modem had the right idea by default.

My Ethernet cord goes from my floor/wall/supply to my modem, from there to a small netgear switch and from there to two different PCs. I don't even know what MoCA or powerline are, I just use an ethernet cable.
I have already swapped out my ethernet cable with the other PC's cable and my issues persist.

May seem obvious, but is there enough drive space for browser cache? Also check virtual memory allocation -- too much, as well as too ;little, can force swapping to disk, vastly slowing operation. (On my PC's, I set initial and max size the same to avoid fragmentation.)

I have enough disk space, yes. As for virtual memory allocation, I have 19.150 MB allocated. At the time of writing this about 11 GB is in use with 8 GB available. I doubt that's the issue though, considering I haven't changed anything with regards to my virtual memory.
From my perspective nothing changed  - no updates, no changes, no install or maintenance of any kind. yet last Friday the issue started for whatever reason.

Do you have any kind of VPN or proxy settings configured on the PC in question?

Nope! No VPN or proxy settings.
